# Set the capsize in seaborn lineplot

Tags: python, seaborn

Is there a way to set the capsize for lineplot in seaborn (with err_style="bars") , in pointplot you can set the capsize with a variable `ax = sns.pointplot(x="day", y="tip", data=tips, capsize=.2)` is it also possible with lineplot (I did not manage to find a variable for it)?

This is the example in seaborn website:

```python
import seaborn as sns; sns.set()
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fmri = sns.load_dataset("fmri")

ax = sns.lineplot(x="timepoint", y="signal", hue="event",
                   err_style="bars", ci=68, data=fmri)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer, the capsize can be changed if we pass a dic with capsize value to err_kws, as follows:

```
import seaborn as sns; sns.set()
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fmri = sns.load_dataset("fmri")

ax = sns.lineplot(x="timepoint", y="signal", hue="event",
                   err_style="bars", ci=68, data=fmri,err_kws={'capsize':1})
```